# How to capture a textchanged event when the textbox is inside a ListView?

Tags: asp.net, listview

I have a series of textbox in a listview which contain the hours and minutes for employees. I want values entered to be computed when any of the textboxes loses focus. I've tried [this exemple from the MSDM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox.textchanged.aspx). For button and LinkButton, I can use **OnItemCommand**, for DDl and listbox, I can use **OnSelectedIndexChanged**.

How about Textchanged for my texboxes? I don't see any event for them. From MSDN, the only method that resemble to that is **TextBox.TextChanged Event**. But it said on that page : "**This API supports the .NET Framework infrastructure and is not intended to be used directly from your code**."

Comment: It's difficult to help without seeing any aspx markup. It's perfectly valid and not obsolete to handle TextBox' the [`TextChanged` event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox.textchanged.aspx). But you could also calculate that on clientside without postback.

Comment: @Tim, as I said in my question, I've tried what you are suggesting, and it's working. The difference is that the textbox is inside a ListView.

Comment: Why is that a difference? The TextBoxes are in the ItemTemplate, aren't they? If they have `AutoPostBack=true` they'll post back as soon as the text changed and the focus lost. Just the same as outside of a ListView.

Comment: How the handler's gonna look like? protected void MyListView_OnChangedText (object sender, EventArgs e) ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `TextBoxes` are in the `ItemTemplate`(or EditItemTemplate), aren't they? If they have `AutoPostBack=true` they'll post back as soon as the text changed and the focus lost. Just the same as outside of a `ListView`.

on aspx:

```
<ItemTemplate>
  <tr runat="server">
    <td>
      <asp:TextBox OnTextChanged="TextBox1_TextChanged" AutoPostBack="true"
            ID="Textbox1" runat="Server" Text="here is text"  />
    </td>
    <td>
  </tr>
</ItemTemplate>
```

in codebehind:

```
protected void TextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   TextBox TextBox1 = (TextBox) sender;
}
```

Comment: It worked perfectly. But the only problem is that, I'd like also to know things such as the DataItemIndex so that I can associate the control and the ListViewItem it belongs to.

Comment: You can get the ListViewItem via textbox' `NamingContainer`: `(ListViewItem) TextBox1.NamingContainer`.

Comment: you're my saviour. God bless you.